# Add element to a double linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I had a task to add an element of type string by index in double linked list. I implemented it as a method of class Double_list. Also I have class List_node.

```
public void Add(String element, int index)
{
    if(index < 0 || index > size)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if(element == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if(index == size)
    {
        this.Add(element);
    }
    else
    {
        List_node next_node = get_node(index);
        List_node prev_node = next_node.prev;

        List_node new_node = new List_node(element, prev_node, next_node);

        next_node.prev = new_node;
        prev_node.next = new_node;
        size++;
    }
}

public boolean Add(String element)
{
    if(element == null)
    { 
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    List_node last = tail.prev;

    List_node new_node = new List_node(element, last, tail);
    last.next = new_node;
    last.prev = new_node;

    size++;
    return true;
}

private List_node get_node(int index)
{
    int cur_index = 0;
    List_node cur_node = head.next;

    while(cur_index < index)
    {
        cur_node = cur_node.next;
        cur_index++;
    }
    return cur_node;
}
```

When I **add several elements**, size of list is increasing but list is displayed in such a way **like I added only one element**. And when I try to remove elements by index which is more than 0 from list I get NullPointerException.
Can you help me and tell me please where I made a mistake?

Comment: You need to post more of your code - specifically, the Add(element) and get_node(index) methods.

Comment: Can you add the exception you get to the post?

Comment: Do you need to increment size after `this.Add(element)`?

Comment: I added methods Add(element) and get_node(index) to this example and details about exception.

Comment: Aside: You should throw an IllegalArgumentException instead of NullPointerException because there is no null "pointer"

Comment: `last.next = new_node; last.prev = new_node;` -- That definitely can't be correct

Comment: cricket_007, thank you. I`ve just realized how inattentive I was. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (with adding, at least, I can't be sure about removing without seeing the code for that too) is that you never update the tail. You add a new element at the tail of the list, and then when you add another you toss the first one out and replace it because tail is still exactly where it started.

In `Add`, change `last.prev = new_node;` to `tail.prev = new_node;`.